# wp_insert_post once a user buys a WooCommerce membership subscription

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am trying to create a new post inside my custom post type 'vipmembers' once the user buys a WooCommerce membership subscription (user role 'subscriber'). The code below only allows me to add a new post once the user is a customer(i.e when user register) but I want the post to only be added once the user buys a WooCommerce membership subscription product (i.e when a user role is Subscriber).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'membership_import', 10, 1 );
function membership_import( $user_id ) {
  if($user_id){
    $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'vipmembers',
      'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
          'key'       => 'user_id',
          'value'     => $user_id,
          'compare'   => '='
        )
      )
    );

    $users_exists = get_posts( $args );
    $author_obj = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
    $roles = $author_obj->roles;
    $post = array(
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($author_obj->user_login),
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_type' => 'vipmembers'
    );
    if(empty($users_exists)){
      $post_ID = wp_insert_post($post);
      update_post_meta($post_ID, 'user_id',$user_id);
      update_post_meta($post_ID, 'user_email',$author_obj->user_email);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anyway got it solved, just changed

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'membership_import', 10, 1 );
function membership_import( $user_id ) {
```

with

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'membership_import');
function membership_import( $order_id ) {
```

:)